# Circle Bundles over complex Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the 'well-known' circle bundle $p:V_{2}(\mathbb{R}^{6})\rightarrow G_{2}(\mathbb{C}^{4})$?
Here $V_{2}(\mathbb{R}^{6})$ denotes the real Stiefel manifold of orthonormal 2 frames and $G_{2}(\mathbb{C}^{4})$ is the complex Grassmannian of two planes.

Comment: You probably need to add some context. Are you reading a paper? A textbook? Some notes? What is the text about? Can you give the entire paragraph?

Comment: I'm guessing this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.1587.pdf